# Install OpenCV 3 Without Upgrading Python

Tags: python, opencv3.0

Python 3.5.2 is installed, and I need to ensure it doesn't upgrade to 3.6 due to some other dependencies.

When I install OpenCV 3 via brew (see below), brew invokes `python3` and upgrades to Python 3.6, the latest build:

`brew install opencv3 --with-python3`

How can I install OpenCV 3 without changing my Python build?

Answer (score 0):

Try using pip, 
You can create a pip-reqs.txt file and pin things to a specific version
Then just run

> pip -r pip-reqs.txt

pip will then take care of installing opencv for you for the python version that is currently configured